# How to trigger image download in sapui5?

Tags: javascript, file, download, sapui5, png

I am currently trying to download a PNG file from my Sapui5 application. I have tried several ways, but all of them only displayed the image in a new or the same tab. The download was never triggered.

I have already tried these ways:

```
    1) URLHelper.redirect
    2) window.open,
    3) window.location.assign,
    4) fetch(URL).then(res => res.blob()).then(blob => {
                            var file = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                            window.location.assign(file);

    5) var link = document.createElement("a");
                        link.href = FullURL;
                        link.download = "QRCode.png";
                        link.target = "_self";
                        document.body.appendChild(link);
                        link.click();
                        document.body.removeChild(link)

    6) sap.ui.core.util.File.save
```

<---- this only results in a file that returns as a message that the file format is probably not supported.

How can I trigger the download?

I am quite new to this and hope you guys can help me. Thanks

Comment: Do the image and the app have the same origin? I.e. is the beginning of the URL the same?

Comment: No, the Image has a different URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution #5 only works if the image and the URL have the same origin (protocol, subdomain, domain and port need to be the same).

Exceptions are `blob` and `data` URLs. So you can combine solution #5 with #4.

I created a [small working example](https://plnkr.co/edit/jBZgwWCW21yqqrUY?preview).

Relevant code is here:

```js
const sURL = 'https://i.imgur.com/q6E7b9d.png';
fetch(sURL)
    .then((oResponse) => oResponse.blob())
    .then((oBlob) => {
        const sBlobURL = URL.createObjectURL(oBlob);
        const oLink = document.createElement('a');
        oLink.href = sBlobURL;
        oLink.download = sURL.split('/').pop();
        oLink.target = '_blank';
        document.body.appendChild(oLink);
        oLink.click();
        document.body.removeChild(oLink);
    });
```

If this also doesn't work then you probably have a CORS issue. Basically the host of your image decides if images can be embedded and downloaded in other pages.